# Retrieving filename used to create Bitmap object (C#)

Tags: c#, constructor, bitmap, filenames

Is there a method/property where you can obtain the filename used to create a bitmap object?

For instance if a bitmap were created somewhere in my main code then passed to a method

```
Bitmap myImage = new Bitmap("C:\\Images\\myImage.bmp");
MyMethod(myImage);
```

How would I get MyMethod to determine the name of the file used to create myImage

```
public void MyMethod(Bitmap myImage)
{
     string imageFileName = // WHAT TO PUT HERE?
}
```

Just to be clear the value of imageFileName in MyMethod should be "C:\\Images\\myImage.bmp".  I would like to avoid creating a global variable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the original file name from the `Bitmap` object.
Since the `Bitmap` class is `sealed`, you can't derive from it.
So create your own wrapper class and hold the `Bitmap` as a member:

```
class myBitmap
{
  Bitmap theBitmap;
  public myBitmap (string image)
  {
    imageFileName = image;  //remember for later.
    theBitmap = new Bitmap(image);
  }
  public string imageFileName {get; set;}
}
```

Then pass a `myBitmap` instance to `MyMethod` and you can get the file name easily.
If you need to access properties of the contained `Bitmap` you will have to create accessor functions in `myBitmap` to do the work for you, since it is a contained object.

Comment: was about to write the same :)